# Mass mv on files and changing filenames

Tags: bash, osx, rename

I want to change these filenames

```
download (19).download
...
download (27).download
```

to

```
download (19).html
...
download (27).html
```

I run unsuccessfully

```
mv *.download *.html
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

**How can you change the filename?**
I think I need a regex here probably.

Comment: This question has been asked here quite often. There should be dozens of duplicates.

Comment: Just learn some scripting language (`awk`?)... this will not only help to solve questions like this one, but zillions of other problems too... really! It's fun... especially `awk` ist rewarding your invested time really fast... only a few hours with an `awk` tutorial and you are settled to gain world domination... mwhuaaahahahahahahahaa!

Comment: @yeti You rename files with `awk`...??

Comment: @HaukeLaging ... yes I can \o/ ... and I can do it in several other languages being installed by default too. I _never_ will install a special file-rename-utility... I am sitting in front of too many different systems (often with only the basic tools being installed) and getting along without "warm-showerer-utilities" has saved my day more than once... so I always vote for learning some swiss army knive tool like `awk` instead of installing a special tool for every differnent fart...

Comment: @yeti The question was **not**: "**Can** you rename files with `awk`"...

Comment: @HaukeLaging ... I really do it sometimes... depending on the context... but that was not the point I wanted to underline with my 1st comment... :-( ...keiner versteht mich!!! )-:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use `mv` to move multiple files to a single directory in on call. One option here is to use `prename` (`rename` is linked to this on most systems, but not all):

```
prename -n 's/download$/html/' -- *.download
```

Remove `-n` when you are sure this is doing what you want. Another way is simply to use a loop:

```
for file in *.download; do
  mv -i -- "$file" "${file%download}html"
done
```

The `-i` option is added `mv` to prompt if any files will be overwritten. Remove this if you are sure that you will not overwrite any files you need.

Comment: I remember answering the same sort of question yesterday where you had suggested `prename`

Comment: @Ramesh, yes, this kind of question has been answered countless times.

Comment: I am now on OSX and so prename command there. Any substitute?

Comment: @Masi, afraid not, there is no standard utility for this kind of thing. The only portable approach is to run `mv` for each file, which can be very slow. `prename` is just a short perl script though. I can't find the original source for it, but it can be downloaded here - https://github.com/subogero/rename

Answer (score 1):

`mv` doesn't work this way. You need another tool like `rename` or `mmv`. Please mind that there are two versions of `rename` around.

And, of course, the shell can do that (with `mv`):

```
for file in *.download; do
  fbasename="${file%.download}"
  if [ -e "${fbasename}.html" ]; then
    echo "${fbasename}.html exists; skipping."
    echo "${fbasename}.html exists; skipping." >>rename.log
    continue
  else
    echo mv -- "$file" "${fbasename}.html"
  fi
done
```

Remove the `echo` after testing.

The `mmv` way:

```
mmv -n '*.download' '#1.html'
```

`-n` prevents execution and shows you what would be done.

Comment: Note that `[ -f ... ]` tests for regular files or symlinks to regular file. If `x.html` is a directory, you'll move `x.download` into that.

Answer (score 0):

`rename 's/download$/html/' *.download` should work for you

Comment: This is `prename` - not all systems have this, others use a different `rename`.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have `zsh` shell available, then `zmv` does almost exactly what you want, with very similar syntax:

```
zmv '*.download' '$1.html'
```

Just to point out why your attempt was wrong and dangerous: the wildcards `*?` are expanded by your shell **before** the command is even called. So, `mv` actually receives the entire list of files instead of `*.download`, but `*.html` has two ways of behaving (both quite bad):

If `*.html` doesn't exist, your shell leaves the asterisk as part of the filename. You are attempting to move all the downloads to the same file named `*.html`. `mv` warns you that it's not a directory (otherwise you would just overwrite this file a number of times and end up with `*.html` containing the last download). If `*.html` does find one or more files, shell expands this into a list of files. Hopefully, none of them are directories, so this fails again for the same reason.

Note that you are extremely lucky, you could have lost data this way.